# How to assign dynamic component reference in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

Given a component, how can we assign component reference dynamically something like so:

`<app-list-audit #LAref{{identifier}}></app-list-audit>`

instead of

`<app-list-audit #LAref2></app-list-audit>`

Comment: It should work that way. What's the problem?

Comment: How can I check whether the reference has been set or not, because when I use viewchild like `@ViewChild('LAref'+this.Identifier) FLADT: Component;`  it shows up undefined

Comment: You need to use viewchildren :)

Comment: Please explain how

Comment: Can you please explain what is your end goal for assigning references to components? Can't you just use viewchildren and querylist to get all references of the components together? And then use the array indexes of the component as references?

Comment: I am using mfDatatable in a component and this component is loaded several times into the page, it is not able to differentiate between the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use references for components that way. I can reference them using the querylist as follows:

```
import { Component, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { AppListComponent } from './applist.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
    <app-list-audit></app-list-audit>
    <app-list-audit></app-list-audit>
    <app-list-audit></app-list-audit> `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren(AppListComponent) list: QueryList<AppListComponent>;
  compArr = [];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.compArr = this.list.toArray();
  }
}
```

And then you can use compArr to reference all the component instances in your template.

Comment: can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: It works thank you. Accepted the answer along with an upvote for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your list-audits in an ngFor:

You can use @ViewChildren with a component selector:

```
export class MyComoponent {
   @ViewChildren(ListAuditComponent) listAudits: QueryList<ListAuditComponent>;
}
```

Comment: let me try to implement this.